# Nuxt.js поддерживают ли макеты из layouts слоты?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

В общем что-то не пойму с логикой.
Есть `default` в `layouts`. В `default` есть например `header`.

Банально: Хочу иметь доступ к замене содержимого в `header`

Пытался сделать в `header` компонент, а на странице его переопределять - ругается `nuxt` на предкомпиляцию.
На слотах тоже как то не вышло. Хотя было поздно и уже сильно хотелось спать.

Можно конечно плюнуть на все и воткнуть инфу по `ID`, но это уже на крайний случай.

С какой стороны подступиться? Может есть какой-нибудь реальный пример такого?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [ответа на github](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/190) от создателя `nuxt.js` насчет поддержки использования слота в файлах макета:

> Это невозможно с `layouts` логикой `nuxt.js`, поскольку он основан на
> `vue-router`.
>
> Но с `vue.js` нет ничего невозможного
>
> Вы можете создать, например, `layout` папку (без `s`), в которой вы можете
> создавать свои макеты со слотами.
>
> **layout/default.vue**
>
> ```
> <template>
>   <div>
>     <header>
>       <slot name="toolbar"></slot>
>     </header>
>     <content>
>       <slot name="content"></slot>
>     </content>
>   </div>
> </template>
> ```
>
> А затем на своих страницах вы можете импортировать макет (мы
> используем его как `<page>`) и использовать слоты:
>
> ```
> <template>
>   <page>
>     <div slot="toolbar">
>       <h2 class="md-title">Welcome to index</h2>
>     </div>
>     <div slot="content">
>       <p>her comes the content...</p>
>     </div>
>  </page>
> </template>
>
> <script>
> import page from '~/layout/default'
>
> export default {
>   components: { page }
> }
> </script>
> ```

В действующих версиях `nuxt.js` - это самый лучший подход для поддержки слотов в макетах.

Comment: Спасибо большое.